# XPath for complicated documents

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have following xml document I need to select all entry nodes where components/section/templateid=3.11 . What should be XPath for that ?

```
     <component>
        <structuredBody>
                <component>
                    <section>
                        <templateId root="1.11"/>           
                        <entry>......</entry>                                                              
                    </section>              
                </component>    
                <component>
                    <section>
                        <templateId root="2.11"/>
                        <templateId root="2.12"/>                   
                        <entry>......</entry>
                        <entry>......</entry>
                    </section>
                </component>
                <component>
                    <section>
                        <templateId root="3.11"/>
                        <templateId root="3.12"/>                   
                        <entry>......</entry>
                        <entry>......</entry>
                    </section>
                </component>            
        <structuredBody>
     </component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this suit your needs?

```
//component/section/templateId[@root='3.11']/following-sibling::entry
```

Comment: I tried that and it didnt return anything .

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention should I be adding namespace in this ?

Comment: Would you suggest any link where I can get list of complex XPath samples ?

Comment: @user1649941: I wouldn't call this one "complex", there are lost more complex ones. [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) is a good starting point, especially [Axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp), [Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp) and [Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp). Also an online Xpath tester would be helpful, like [this one](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).